# SFINAE still produces error while using exception

Tags: c++, templates, exception, c++14, sfinae

I am learning about SFINAE in C++. So after reading about it, i am trying out different examples to better understand the concept. Below i have given 2 snippets out of which 1 i can understand but the second one where i have used `noexcept` in the declaration i can't understand.

**Example 1**: I am able to understand this.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
decltype(func(T())) timer(T a) 
{
    std::cout<<"template timer called"<<std::endl;
    return func(T());
}

void timer(...)
{
    std::cout<<"ordinary timer called"<<std::endl;   
}
int main()
{
    timer(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program(as expected) is:

```
ordinary timer called
```

I can understand that due to SFINAE the deduction will result in failure and so the ordinary `timer` will be called.

**Example 2**: Why do we get error in this example.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void timer(T a) noexcept(func(T()))
{
    std::cout<<"template timer called"<<std::endl;
}

void timer(...)
{
    std::cout<<"ordinary timer called"<<std::endl;   
}
int main()
{
    timer(5);
    return 0;
}
```

This second example results in an error saying that `func` was not declared. My question is why just like example 1 here also due to deduction failure the ordinary `timer` isn't selected?

I expected that here also ordinary `timer` should have been called but it isn't the case. Can someone explain the reason behind it.

Comment: what is `func` ?

Comment: The problem is that **exception specification** do not participate in template argument deduction.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number `func` does not exist.

Comment: @AnoopRana can you explain in more detail.

Comment: @AnoopRana Thanks for the detailed answer and mentioning the source. Now i can read more about the topic from the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that **exception specification** do not participate in **template argument deduction(TAD)**. This is explained in more detail below. [Source: C++ Templates: The Complete Guide Page No. 290](https://www.amazon.in/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0321714121)

##### Case 1

Here we consider example 1. In this case, since there is no `func` the error in the declaration of the function template `timer` **triggers** template argument deduction failure aka SFINAE which allows the call `timer(5);` to succeed by selecting the ordinary function `timer` and you get the expected output.

##### Case 2

Here we consider example 2. In this case, because exception specification do not participate in TAD, **overload resolution** selects the function template version and so when the exception specification is instantiated at later time, the program becomes **ill-formed** and you get the mentioned error.

In other words, exception specifications are only instantiated when needed just like **default call arguments**.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: SFINAE is about substitution not deduction

Comment: for example here https://godbolt.org/z/53cj1rfTa. Nothing has to be deduced

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Apparently books seems to contradict with your opinion. I quote from C++ Templates Page No. 284: The Complete Guide: *"The SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error) is
an important aspect of template argument deduction"*

Comment: when the argument is not specificied it must be deduced, but for SFINAE that doesn't matter because SFINAE is about substitution

Comment: @I have mentioned the name and page number of the book. It is a go to book for C++ templates. Moreover, they have the exact same explanation as i have given in this answer(or rather i have the exact same explanation as them) of exception specification on Page number 290.

Comment: fwiw, I deleted comments, because as it stands it looks a little odd to reject a quote from a book saying "I don't know where from". The referecne with name and page has been edited in afterwards and anyhow what I wanted to comment is already in the first two comments.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ok. Also i agree that sfinae doesn't have to be "always" associated with deduction. For example, if we specify the template arguments explicitly.