# Usage of decltype in return type of function template removes error due to exception specification

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, function-templates, function-templates-overloading

I saw an answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71510209/sfinae-still-produces-error-while-using-exception). There the author of the answer made use of the fact that

> exception specifications do not participate<sup>1</sup> in template argument deduction.

In the answer linked above it is explained why the following doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void timer(T a) noexcept(func(T()))
{
    std::cout<<"template timer called"<<std::endl;
}

void timer(...)
{
    std::cout<<"ordinary timer called"<<std::endl;   
}
int main()
{
    timer(5);//won't compile
    return 0;
}
```

it is [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71510324/15545927) that because exception specification do not participate in TAD, overload resolution selects the function template version and so when the exception specification is instantiated at later time, the program becomes ill-formed and we get the error.

Now i modified the above program to see if i understand the topic correctly. In particular, i have added `decltype(func(T()))` as the return type of the function template version(as shown below) and then the error goes away:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(func(T())) timer(T a) noexcept(func(T())) //return type added here
{
    std::cout<<"template timer called"<<std::endl;
    return func(T());//return statement added here
}

void timer(...)
{
    std::cout<<"ordinary timer called"<<std::endl;   
}
int main()
{
    timer(5); //works now? 
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, why when we add the return type to the function template as shown above, the error has gone away?

PS: My question is not about why the first example gives error works but it is rather why the modified example doesn't give error.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>This quote is from [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=i7M1DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT511&ots=4iXL3T7Fy8&dq=exception%20specification%20do%20not%20participate%20in%20template%20argument%20deduction%20c%2B%2B%20templates%20the%20complete%20guide&pg=PT511#v=onepage&q=exception%20specification%20do%20not%20participate%20in%20template%20argument%20deduction%20c++%20templates%20the%20complete%20guide&f=false).</sup>

Comment: Because now due to SFINAE in the return type of the function template, it(the function template) is ignored due to subsitution failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here since there is no `func`, so during the **substitution** of the template argument(s) in the return type of the function template, we get **substitution failure** and due to SFINAE this function template is not added to the set. In other words, it is **ignored**.

Thus the call `timer(5);` uses the ordinary function `timer` since it is the only viable option now that the function template has been ignored. Hence the program compiles and gives the output:

```
ordinary timer called
```